# Can PHP load a page containing specific content into an iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

I have an internal page on my site that contains an iframe. The content inside the iframe consists of 3 pages, a.htm, b.htm, and c.htm.  By default, a.htm loads when I visit the page containing the iframe.

On the homepage of my site, there are 2 links...one links to content on b.htm, the other to content on c.htm. So when one of these links are clicked, I need to load the page on my site that contains the iframe, with either b.htm or c.html showing inside it, depending on which link was clicked.

I know basic PHP, but I'm struggling to find a way to pass the iframe content into the frame from an external page. Or would jQuery be better suited for this? I've looked through a lot of submissions about this, but haven't found an answer that works for me yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: with out reloading the outside page you would need some client side code (javaScript), if you dont mind reloading then you could use php

Comment: Reloading wouldn't a problem in this case because all referral links come from external pages. I'm open to either a JS or PHP solution.

Comment: so then just change the src url for iframe in the page

Comment: JS: `document.getElementById("iframeID").src = "b.html";`

Comment: I was just experimenting with this very idea in js. I guess my confusion is how to set the iframe source based on which button is clicked on the homepage. Im assuming I need to use a referral value.

Comment: The answer is yes. The answer to question how is; it depends on your implementation. No we can't write it for you, yes we're here to help. No, I'm not a smartass. Yes if you write sufficient code, and still have a bug, we gladly help you. Yes, you can go to chat channels, to discuss such implementation plans.